# I wonder why range of spectral index map by imshow is different with theoretical value

Tags: python, imshow

From fits file I got D1 and D2 data.
min and max value of D1 and D2 is like this
[image: 1]

Since I'm trying to get spectral index value which formula is like this
[image: 2]

I made my code like this
[image: 3]
[D1 is flux data for 22 GHz frequency and D2 is flux data for 43 GHz frequency].

Theoretically estimated result range is -2~2, however when I draw the imshow image of the result it seems like this.
!
Which shows the range of -15~15.

Therefore I wonder why this happens. Is there something I did wrong or I don't know about?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please consider posting code as text (your images #1 and #3). As for the root of the question, I think you should normalize somehow your D1 and D2 first. As the range of D2 from -0.79 to +17.70 spans zero, the expression D1/D2 may be undefined.

Comment: Thank you for your comment:) With your advice, I could find out the problem and figure it out! Thank you once again!